# Java generics new object

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a new object of a generic class, and I can do 
`Example <T> a = new Example()` or `Example <T> a = new Example<T>()`.
Only in the first case, there is a warning saying "Pair is a raw type. References to generic type Pair should be parameterized", but since now, both way worked for me. Also I can leave out the generics at the left side or both side and same warning appear. What is the difference? Is there any cases where they make a difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its true, the code compile and run as it should.

Comment: Object was just an example, any generic class could work

Comment: Could you put the actual code you compiled and ran into the question?

Answer (score 1):

difference is after the assignment operator

```
new Example()
```

is a raw type whereas

```
new Example<T>()
```

is generic because you are passing a generic type argument. You can also use diamond operator

```
Example<T> a = new Example<>()
```

Comment: so the last two syntaxes are the same?

Comment: and why should I specify the generic arguments in the diamond operator if I dont have to? because my code still run without specifying

Comment: yes, last 2 syntaxes are same. You don't have to specify generic type argument because of diamond operator but without using `Example<T>()` or `Example<>()`, you are using raw type instead of generic type

Answer (score 0):

The following example will help you understand the concept better:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List list1 = new ArrayList();// List and ArrayList are raw types

        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();// ArrayList is a raw type

        List list3 = new ArrayList<>();// List is a raw type

        List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();// No warning of raw type anymore

        List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<>();// The type in the right diamond is optional

        // List<> list6=new ArrayList<>();//Won't compile - the type in the left diamond is mandatory
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code snippets

```
Example<A> e = new Example<A>();
Example<A> e = new Example<>();
Example<A> e = new Example();
Example e = new Example();
Example e = new Example<A>();
```

will all generate the same binary code (lookup "Type Erasure").

But when you omit the generic argument, you will kick out the door the compiler's capability to do a proper type checking, and you may make your code more difficult to read. That's why the compiler emits that warning ("Example is a raw type. References to generic type Example should be parameterized.") – But it is still a warning …

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: I trust your word ...